# hosts file ignored

Tags: windows-xp, hosts

This is very strange issue. I'm on Windows XP. I have tried to put

```
41.41.41.41 facebook.com
41.41.41.41 www.facebook.com
```

into `C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc/hosts`. When I tried to save the file, it said me I do not have enough permissions (I'm admin). So I have just deleted the hosts file and saved the one I wanted. Suddenly, when I go to facebook.com, Facebook login screen appears. When I try to

```
ping www.facebook.com
```

I get (translated following text from Czech)

```
Command PING to www.facebook.com [41.41.41.41] with 32 bytes length:

Response from 41.41.41.41: bajts=32 time=66ms TTL=53
Response from 41.41.41.41: bajts=32 time=81ms TTL=53
Response from 41.41.41.41: bajts=32 time=114ms TTL=53
Response from 41.41.41.41: bajts=32 time=123ms TTL=53
```

(I have real IP instead of `41.41.41.41`, but I don't want to share it here)

Even worse thing is, that when I try to go to https://facebook.com, I get connection error (Because it's problably trying to connect the server specified, which doen't have the https supported

Why is this happening? Is there some specific reason why is it still connecting to facebook?

Additionally, I have tried to / I know that

- flush DNS with cmd
- checked if I'm not using browser's proxy (no, I'm not)
- connect to https://facebook.com - it fails, it means that the real Facebook server isn't reached when using https
- AVG has expired lincense, therefore it shouldn't act on my PC anymore
- that the same problem happens on IE and on Firefox, too

Comment: The obvious, have you cleared the DNS resolver cache? `ipconfig /flushdns`

Comment: Does the '41.41.41.41' IP address exist locally?

Comment: @Sathya: yeah, + restarted Firefox

Comment: @HaydnWVN: no, I don't want to share the real IP - `(I have real IP instead of 41.41.41.41, but I don't want to share it here)`

Comment: Start notepad (or notepad++, or whatever you use) with admin permissions (run as administrator) and then you can save the edited file

Comment: As the IP address doesn't exist then the request is handed to your DNS server, if unavailable/automatic (and you have a gateway specified) then the request is going out to your ISP's DNS server which you have no control over.

Comment: @Linker3000: I'm on XP, XP has no "run as administrator" as far as I know

Comment: @HaydnWVN: It does exist!

Comment: I asked if it existed locally (ie on your network) and you said no?

Comment: @HaydnWVN: Please read my question again. My real server IP is changed here for this question, I do not want to share it. The real one IS accessible from my network.

Comment: At no point did you say the '41.41.41.41' address was your server, which is more than likely running as a DNS server... Think about what you've done - Just avoided the local machines DNS and pointed it straight back at your server's DNS.

Comment: @HaydnWVN the request wouldn't go to the DNS server it will look at hosts and only if hosts has no record will it then go to the DNS server. if the server on that IP is up or Down has no bearing on it.

Comment: Ah, i assumed it did, especially with a gateway and automatic DNS servers. Sorry genesis, seems my troubleshooting was inaccurate.

Comment: Is this question a dupe of: http://superuser.com/questions/252452/browsers-ignoring-hosts-file?

Comment: @Ivo it would normally be, but I'd say it's more related than a dupe - On https, it's really going to my IP because it fails to connect as assumed

Answer (score 1):

Firefox has a built-in DNS cache.

To clear it, you can use the add-on [clear dns cache](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/clear-dns-cache/).

Comment: I have tried it with IE, with no effect

Comment: Are you using a router or a proxy server? Both might be caching DNS entries.

Comment: as I have hosts file in place, with IP, I assume it should not request DNS.

Comment: If `https://facebook.com` works but `http://facebook.com` does not, it is clearly a caching issue.