# Custom entry in hosts file not directing to correct IP

Tags: ip, hosts, dnsmasq

I have an entry in my local hosts file pointing to:

```
$my-server-ip development.$client-domain.com
```

When I ping `development.$client-domain.com`, I get $server-ip, but when I visit it in a browser, I do not get what is at `$my-server-ip`, instead I get `$client-domain.com`'s content.

I suspect that this has to do with a recent install of `dnsmasq`, but if it is I am not certain how to go about resolving this problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Browsers ignoring hosts file](http://superuser.com/questions/252452/browsers-ignoring-hosts-file)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 You are probably right. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

So, it turns out that @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 is right, this is a duplicate... of sorts. However, instead of the proxying happening at the browser or OS level, it is a network proxy which is overriding local settings. It is reading the request header and it is then redirecting.